# website CSS files would load affer publish

Tags: html, css

I made this website bigeyeslion.com years ago with a template. Recently, I changed some text and images. After that the CSS stop working. I test it locally before upload to server, it worked fine. but the css files just wont load on the server. Here is the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

    <title>Leon Sun - Creative Designer - Graphic and 3D</title>

        <meta name="description" content="Leon Sun, Creative Designer,Graphic, 3D, Display design"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Leon Sun, Creative Designer,Graphic, 3D, Display design"/>
        <meta name="author" content="bigeyeslion.com"/>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png"> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-responsive.css" />               

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

I put the css files in a folder public_html/css and index is in public_html folder.

Please help, I been struggle with this for days

Comment: If you're using google chrome press `F12`, it should show you if there are any errors loading the resources

Answer (score 0):

I find it very strange. I test the site on a MAC with firefox and on a PC with google Chrome at my working place. both of them show the same problem. with F12, it tells me I have 2 img (which I did not use) were missing. But when test at home with chrome it works fine and also working on a cellphone too.